# Printing with the browser in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, printing

I have a Silverlight 4 app which is essentially a canvas filled with user-drawn controls.  When I use Print (or Print Preview) in Firefox 3.6, the canvas is not displayed.

Every example wrt printing in Silverlight creates a Print button within their Silverlight app.  Isn't there a browser event I can hook into (or something) so that the user can print from the browser instead of the application?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to invoke the browser print method with:-

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("print");
```

Note that (if it works at all) this will only print the visible portion of the Silverlight plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a Microsoft-specific `beforeprint` [event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events).  But, in general, I think you're out of luck.  Even with Microsoft, the print event cannot be cancelled, so the page would print in addition to the application.